# Probability of that an action unit backs to it's original price in 6 days

Tags: probability, percentages

Each day the price of a particular stock rises or falls, the probability of the price up is 3/4 and 1/4 the probability that the price down , What is the probability that in six days the action back to its original price ? . help I calculate the propabilities for the two cases, I optain the probability of $(3/4)^6$ when the action up, and $(1/4)^6$ when the action it's down but I don´t understand how to calculate the part when the price backs to it's original value, any help will be appreciated

Comment: Assume independence, which may not be reasonable. Also rises, falls by how much?  A fixed amount, like a dollar? There are many other ways to rise and fall. But say fixed amount. Then we want to have the probability of exactly three rise days and exactly $3$ fall days. Binomial distribution.

Comment: thanks, I did the operations and it works

Comment: You are welcome.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$$\binom63\cdot\left(\frac14\right)^{3}\cdot\left(1-\frac14\right)^{6-3}$$